# How to correct from getting Internal Server Error with Joomla

Tags: templates, joomla

Help
I am working on my joomla! 2.5.6 site and have done something to cause an issue on the front end and the back end.
These are the steps I did to create the issues.
Created a template in Artisteer 4 beta to use as a secondary template, not default.
I tried to delete the template but it told me that I could not delete the last template style.
I used FileZilla FTP to delete that template
The template manager still showed that template in the list.
I read that I had to use the ext manager to delete the template.
I uploaded the template back into a new directory as the same name as the one I previously deleted.
I then deleted the template correctly using the ext manager.
I decided to begin using rt-gantry v3.2.22 as my default template

Now, as I am making mods to this I am constantly met with a 500 Internal Server error. Most times just refreshing the page will take me to the page I wanted and sometimes it takes 2,3,4,5 refreshes to do it.

On the front end after I save a change and refresh the page, I may not see the change unless I refresh it several times. There are some instances that the page displays without any CSS, sometimes it displays with old data. Eventually it will display the saved changes correctly.

How can I find the source of this issue and correct it. 
Thanks in advance,
Jeff
url is www.lastingimpressionwebdesign.com

Comment: First; install your site on your local development computer and open the php (or apache-error) log files to check the 500 errors, so you can check what is going wrong. (or if possible check them on the server)

Answer (score 0):

Its a little confusing keeping track of what is or isn't there, but if you're able to get into the admin, then clearly it's a template issue.  All the files, of course, need to be there, but there has to be an entry in the jos_extensions table to match them.  Also, I'm suspicious of your comment that you're using *rt-gantry v3.2.22* as your "template" - that is a *framework* for templates, not a template itself.  You may want to update or re-install Gantry to insure you have a complete installation of it as well.

In short, I'd suggest reverting everything to a standard Joomla template such as Beez, *get the front-end working, and *then* start gradually adding back your choice in templates with overrides/assignments one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the ownership or permissions of your file. It could also be your hosting provider's server environment and how PHP is configured. It's hard to say without looking at the logs.

Comment: If you need more elements to answer, you can ask for them in the comments.